# Convert variables in data.table to formula

Tags: r, data.table

I have a sample data.table `data` as below:

```
   VarName Formulae
1:       A      1+1
2:       B      A+3
3:       C     B*10
4:       D      A+C
5:       E      D/2
```

I want to convert the `Formulae` column into formulas, so that the output can become like:

```
  VarName Result
1:       A      2
2:       B      5
3:       C      50
4:       D      52
5:       E      26
```

Basically the `VarName` column is the variable name and the `Formulae` column is the corresponding formula.

```
A = 1+1
B = A+3
C = B*10
D = A+C
E = D/2
```

I have tried using the `eval` and `parse` functions like `data$VarName = eval(parse(text = "data$Formulae"))`, however I could not get the desired output.

Comment: Could you add more example rows?

Comment: @zx8754 edited the question with more example rows added and more elaboration

Comment: Great, are formulaes always that simple, and follow pattern,  add 1 to previous row value?

Comment: Are they always going to be sequential? i.e. the next one will be based on the previous?

Comment: No, the actual formulaes are a lot more complicated, I only used this as a simple example for illustration

Comment: Are they sequential? Please add more realistic example, is it always addition, do you have other operators as well? Possible solution would be a recursive function, that keeps running until all values on result column are computed as numeric.

Comment: @zx8754 No they are not sequential, I have edited the question so that the formulas are more similar to my actual data. It can be any operators, not only addition

Comment: Provided the answer, seems overly simplistic, test with the real data and let us know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert `Formulae` to actual one-sided formulae and then functions which are in turn evaluated inside of `lst()` which allows for the sequential building of objects.  This relies on the metaprogramming functionality of the `tidyverse` framework rather than `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(VarName = LETTERS[1:5],
                 Formulae = c("1+1", "A+3", "B*10", "A+C", "D/2"))

lst(!!!map(set_names(df$Formulae, df$VarName),
           ~ quo(
             as_mapper(reformulate(.x))()
           )))
$A
[1] 2

$B
[1] 5

$C
[1] 50

$D
[1] 52

$E
[1] 26
```

Or alternatively:

```
lst(!!!set_names(df$Formulae, df$VarName) %>% map(str2lang))
```

As noted in the comments below these require that the formulae are in a sequential order.

Comment: The output is a list?

Comment: @zx8754 - yes it's a list.

Comment: This works too! I think this method is more direct compared to @zx8754's method, hence I would mark this as the solution.

Comment: @debster This only works when the data is in this specific order. Change the order of this dataframe and this solution won't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Loop through *VarName* replace them with *Formulae* within brackets, then evaluate:

```
res <- setNames(x$Formulae, x$VarName)

while(any(grepl(paste0(names(res), collapse = "|"), res))) {
  for(i in names(res)){
    res <- gsub(i, paste0("(", res[ i ], ")"), res, fixed = TRUE)
  }
}

#res, after replacements:
#                          A                          B 
#                      "1+1"                  "(1+1)+3" 
#                          C                          D 
#             "((1+1)+3)*10"     "(1+1)+(((1+1)+3)*10)" 
#                          E 
# "((1+1)+(((1+1)+3)*10))/2" 

# evaluate
sapply(res, function(i) eval(parse(text = i)))
#A  B  C  D  E 
#2  5 50 52 26
```

Comment: To make it more general, you could reformulate the while-condition to: `any(grepl(paste0(names(res), collapse = "|"), res))`

Answer (score 3):

It's interesting to see another function for this task that can be useful in more complex (where the order of evaluation is not specified) cases -- `delayedAssign` assings a value to a name and only evaluates it when requested. This way, each object is evaluated sequentially until its value is reached. For example, consider the following "data.frame":

```
d = structure(list(v = c("a", "b", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                   f = c("C+b", "A+B/D", "1+1", "A+3", "B*10", "A+C", "D/2")), 
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Then we setup a new environment (to avoid cluttering `.GlobalEnv`) and assign our variables:

```
e = new.env()
forms = parse(text = d$f)
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) do.call(delayedAssign, list(d$v[i], forms[[i]], e, e))
```

And evaluate:

```
unlist(mget(ls(e), e)) #or
unlist(eapply(e, eval))
#        A         B         C         D         a         E         b 
# 2.000000  5.000000 50.000000 52.000000 52.096154 26.000000  2.096154
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` :

```
df <- data.frame("VarName"=c("X","Y"),"Formulae"=c("1+1","X+1"))
df$formulas <- apply(df,1,function(x)eval(parse(text = paste0(x["VarName"]," ~ ",x["Formulae"]))))
```

Using `eval(parse(...))` structure was correct, but this should work properly. However, maybe someone will answer a cleaner proposition.

Take note that column "formulas" can not be a vector, so it is a list.

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ VarName : chr  "X" "Y"
 $ Formulae: chr  "1+1" "X+1"
 $ formulas:List of 2
  ..$ :Class 'formula'  language X ~ 1 + 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000002933f8904a8> 
  ..$ :Class 'formula'  language Y ~ X + 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x000002933fb6f3b8>
```

This can cause some headaches in dataframes usage. I suggest using mapping tools like `purrr` instead of concatening everything into a dataframe in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However the codes doesn't seem to produce the output that I want :/